# Matrix of pairs from two arrays in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, perceptron, neural-network

I have a couple of arrays:

```
x = [0:pi/16:2*pi] 
y = [0:pi/16:2*pi]
```

And I want to make a matrix xy in this way:

```
xY = [(0,0)      (0,pi/16)      ...     (0,2pi);
      (pi/16,0)  (pi/16,pi/16)  ...     (pi/16,2pi);
          :            :                     :
      (2pi,0)    (2pi,pi/16)    ...     (2pi,2pi)]
```

I've tried many things like this:

```
for i=1:length(x)
    for j=1:length(y)
        xy{i,j} = [{x(i),y(j)}];
    end
end
```

, but I have encountered many errors.

I know it should be easy, and the biggest problem is that the title of my post (and because of that, the way I'm looking for help) is wrong, so I apologize for that.

I think I should mention that I'm trying to create a multi-layer perceptron that will get trained with that matrices and this formula:

```
fxy = cos(x)-3*sin(y);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) is designed for.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to this is to create matrix of size `length(x)`-by-`length(y)`-by-`2`:

```
 A = zeros(length(x), length(y), 2);
 for i = 1 : length(x); for j = 1 : length(y); A(i, j, :) = [x(i), y(j)]; end; end;
```

In your case, matrix `A` will have size `33x33x2`. To get pair using indexes `i, j` use the following code:

```
 squeeze(A(i, j, :))
```

Or you can adjust your code to work with such 3-dimensional matrix.